# From client cancel server socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Have a large slow feed over a .NET asynchronous socket.  Data is coming from instruments so can be 1 row a second (or more).  Some times it can just stall.

Using there two examples from MSDN
[asynchronous-client-socket-example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example)
[asynchronous-server-socket-example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example)

I have a requirement **from** the socket client stop the transfer from the server mid stream.  Each message is pretty small.  Do not need to stop mid message.  Need to be able to stop the loop - can receive 1000s of small messages (to client).

My thought is to save a reference to `client` and call:

```
client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
client.Close();
```

Is this the correct approach?

```
private static Socket client;
private static void StartClient()
{
    // Connect to a remote device.  
    try
    {
        // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  
        // The name of the   
        // remote device is "host.contoso.com".  
        //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("host.contoso.com"); Dns.GetHostName()
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        //client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
        //    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
        connectDone.WaitOne();

        // Send test data to the remote device.  
        Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
        sendDone.WaitOne();

        // Receive the response from the remote device.  
        Receive(client);
        receiveDone.WaitOne();

        // Write the response to the console.  
        Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

        // Release the socket.  
        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        client.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It is cleaner to send a command to server to stop processing.  Then have server send a response indicating it completed the command.  The n Close connection from client.

Comment: @jdweng  I don't follow.   I do get a response from the server.  And I could get 1000 more.  I want to tell the server to stop sending.

Comment: Do you control the server's implementation? If so, you would implement a command which would cause the server to (optionally) send an acknowledgement message and then shut down the socket, On the client side, that would look like an End of File event, and then you would close the client socket.

Comment: If you don't control the server, and there is no such command, then your only option is to close the socket from the client side. The down side to that approach is that the server cannot tell whether the client shut down "gracefully", or there was some kind of network error, so logging becomes tricky.

Comment: @glenebob I control the server.   It is not that kind of event.  The event is the user is tired of waiting and wants to just cancel.

Comment: No, you're missing it. The command would be a message sent from the client to the server. A "goodbye", so to speak. The server would respond by closing the socket.

Comment: @glenebob I will look into that.

Comment: Glenebob : NEVER CLOSE A CONNECTION FROM THE SERVER.

Comment: I don't see a point in sending any message. If you are done (don't need and don't expect any messages from server any more) - just close connection like you are doing now. There are already "messages" (FIN packet) when tcp connection is closing, no need for your own protocol on top of that.

Comment: If the server needs to do cleanup or close files, it needs a message.  There is any way of capturing the closing event at the server.

Comment: @jdweng Server does not need to clean up anything.  What I am trying now is come at it from the other end.  Client asks for the next reading.  If client does not want more then simply stops asking.

Comment: I'm just specifying the correct methods.  Do what you want.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your help.